# Proving the unitary relation of ensemble decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

I apologize if this is better suited for physics.stackexchange; looking at previously asked questions it seems as if this would be a good fit here, as the arguments are mostly mathematical.

In my class it was told that ensemble decompositions of a density operator $\rho$ are not unique, but that the ones that exist are related by a unitary operator. I'm trying to prove this, but I get stuck somewhere along the way.

Lets begin by assuming two different decompositions of density operator $\rho$:
$\rho = \sum_{j=1}^n{p_j|\psi_j\rangle\langle\psi_j|} = \sum_{k=1}^m{q_k|\phi_k\rangle\langle\phi_k|}$

Now, these two decompositions live in a Hilbert space A. We can then define a purification of both, using a system B of dimension equal to the largest of $n,m$, so that we get 
$|\Psi_1\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{j=1}^n{\sqrt{p_j}|\psi_j\rangle \otimes |b_j\rangle}$ and $|\Psi_2\rangle_{AB} = \sum_{k=1}^m{\sqrt{q_k}|\phi_k\rangle \otimes |b_k\rangle}$.

Now, here we can use that as these pure states are purifications of the same density operator, there must be a unitary $U$ connecting them: $(1_A \otimes U_B)|\Psi_1\rangle_{AB} = |\Psi_2\rangle_{AB}$.

Here is where I get stuck. I should be able to use this to prove the unitary relation between the $\psi$ and the $\phi$, but it is not obvious to me how I should do this.